# Black screen after suspend-after moving to the nvidia official drivers (not priority)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, suspend

So, when I used the priority drivers, the suspend worked normal. But the official drivers works better, so I installed the official driver. Then suspend won't work.

Should I change any text/documants to make it work?
Any solution will be aprreciated, thanks you all!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

- [Screen Doesn't Display After Resume using X-Swat Nvidia Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153691/screen-doesnt-display-after-resume-using-x-swat-nvidia-drivers)

Use the `nvidia-current-updates` driver instead of the `nvidia-current` driver. That fixed the problem for me.