# Screen Doesn't Display After Resume using X-Swat Nvidia Drivers

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, suspend, vaio

I upgraded the Nvidia Drivers from the X-Swat ppa on my Sony Vaio VPCF1390X laptop. Everything seems to be working great, but suspend/resume. The laptop successfully suspends and seems to resume;the screen backlighting comes on, but the screen is blank. It won't comeback until I force a reboot. This issue is 100% reproducible every time.
Resume worked perfectly before the update, so it's seems to be Nvidia driver related. I realize I could probably go back the the previous default proprietary drives, but I'd like to make this work.

Current Nvidia driver version is 302.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resume is not currently working for some cards with 302.17.  You can track the status of the issue here:

http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=179956

nVidia is aware and working on a fix, but there is no ETA yet.  302.17 is a beta driver btw.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something stupid.

Comment: 302.17 is not a beta version - it's their latest stable release.

Comment: Since nvnews went bust with DDoS attacks, and isn't likely to have anything to do with linux once the owner restores the site.. Is there anywhere else to follow this issue?

Comment: the link is dead. Have anything else?