# Computer shuts down after some hours of sleeping while unplugged

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

When I put my computer to sleep, close its lid, and unplug the power from the wall, then it will shut down automatically after about 2 hours. It is not like the battery is dying, because when this happens the battery generally is about 98% fully charged. Sometimes when I open the lid the screen becomes black and I can solve the problem by changing the brightness via the keyboard. But I am not talking about this problem. The computer really shuts down, it is not just a black screen problem.

I don't have a problem with the battery, because it can stand a long time unplugged if the computer is not sleeping.

How do I stop this problem? When this happens I lose all browser windows and other things.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My computer is Aspire V5-572G-6679. I have dual boot along side windows 8.1. I have Nvidia Geforce GT 720M.

PS: sleeping = suspended.

Answer (score 1):

For several people, this was an issue with NVIDIA drivers and was solved by installing the latest proprietary drivers.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers
```

(or **sudo apt-get install nvidia-current**)

I hope it will work for you!

Comment: This might be also possible duplicate of [Screen Doesn't Display After Resume using X-Swat Nvidia Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153691/screen-doesnt-display-after-resume-using-x-swat-nvidia-drivers) if you have NVIDIA driver version 302.17

Comment: I wrote in my question that this is not the problem. The  computer shuts down. I am not complaining about when the screen doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

There was a feature that Intel motherboards came out with a while back called [rapid start](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/what-is-intel-rapid-start-technology) to automatically convert from suspend mode to hibernate mode after a timeout that I believe defaulted to two hours.  Have a look around at your bios options and try to disable it.

Comment: I didn't find any relevant option in my bios. Besides that I tested hibernating with `sudo pm-hibernate` and it hibernated correctly and didn't shut down. So I think this is not the problem.

Comment: @cesarsalgado, yes, the problem is that the ability to seamlessly convert from suspend to hibernation involves doing a hybrid suspend where the system writes the hibernation data *and* preserves the ram, up until the timer expires, then it just shuts down and relies on the hibernation data.  Since Ubuntu doesn't do a hybrid suspend normally, the shutdown just loses your data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @psusi, but how will I disable this feature if there is no relevant option in the bios?

Comment: I don't think I have rapid start technology, because I don't have a SSD card and in windows the intel icon from rapid start doesn't appear too.